# Why does aws-okta add fail?

Tags: wsl2

I am trying to run `aws-okta add` on WSL2, but it fails because `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` isn't define:

```
$ aws-okta --debug add
Okta organization: company

Okta region ([us], emea, preview):

Okta domain [company.okta.com]:

Okta username: username

DEBU[0008] Keyring key: okta-creds
Okta password:

DEBU[0014] domain: company.okta.com
DEBU[0014] Step: 1
DEBU[0016] Step: 2
INFO[0016] Requesting MFA. Please complete two-factor authentication with your second device
DEBU[0016] MFAConfig: {  phone1}
INFO[0016] Select a MFA from the following list
INFO[0016] 0: OKTA (token:software:totp)
INFO[0016] 1: OKTA (sms)
INFO[0016] 2: OKTA (push)
Select MFA method: 2

DEBU[0018] Okta Factor Provider: OKTA
DEBU[0018] Okta Factor ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEBU[0018] Okta Factor Type: push
DEBU[0053] Failed to add user to keyring: No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /
Failed to set credentials in your keyring
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows:

```
$ dbus-launch
```

open an [Xlaunch](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/IDH_DISPLAY.htm) app on the host Windows machine and a new `keyring` window will pop up in case one want to add a secret key.